# Merge or concat three data frames on two different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have three data frames.

```
d.head()

        hotel          DATE
0   Resort Hotel    2015-07-01
1   Resort Hotel    2015-07-01
2   Resort Hotel    2015-07-01
3   Resort Hotel    2015-07-01
4   Resort Hotel    2015-07-01
```

```
r_w.head()
            hotel       DATE       PRCP TAVG
4744    Resort Hotel    2015-07-01  0.0 70
4745    Resort Hotel    2015-07-02  0.0 73
4746    Resort Hotel    2015-07-03  0.0 74
4747    Resort Hotel    2015-07-04  0.0 76
4748    Resort Hotel    2015-07-05  0.0 80
```

```
c_w.head()
          hotel     DATE        PRCP  TAVG
7111    City Hotel  2015-07-01  0.00    68
7112    City Hotel  2015-07-02  0.09    69
7113    City Hotel  2015-07-03  0.00    70
7114    City Hotel  2015-07-04  0.00    74
7115    City Hotel  2015-07-05  0.00    71
```

Data frame `d` has ~100,000 rows and the two other data frames have ~500 rows. I am trying to add `PRCP` and `TAVG` columns to data frame `d` based on columns `hotel` and `DATE`. I have tried

```
d.merge(r_w, how='outer', on=['hotel', 'DATE'])
```

but I get the error:

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

To solve this issue, I tried to do `r_w.loc['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(r_w.DATE)` but I still get the same error with the following warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)
```

How do I merge/concat the columns and what does the warning mean?

Comment: Use `r_w['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(r_w.DATE)` without `.loc` ?

Comment: @SeaBean I get another warning and 4 additional columns: `PRCP_x`, `PRCP_y`, `TAVG_x` and `TAVG_y` with NaNs. I don't want 4 additional columns.

Comment: `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy`

Comment: You mean you go through the ValueError by amending the code above without .loc ?

Comment: @SeaBean Yes but the warning seems like it's asking me to use `.loc`.

Comment: The SettingWithCopyWarning error mostly is for chained assignment for DataFrame.  When you do it on the Date column, it is a Series.  So should not be related to this statement.  Also, this way of using .loc will only give you unexpected result of appending a row with index 'DATE' at the end.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: I cannot simulate your problem and don't know how your dataframes may have copied from.  So can't give you a concrete answer.  So, see if the post above can give you hint.

Comment: What is the expected output?